# Prevent LF adding in XML file while converting

Tags: php, xml, ascii, xmlconvert

I use PHP to convert XML into XML.

While the conversion operates nicely, I have LF that appears after HTML tags. ie:

```
The weather was <i>nice</i> and Eve was feeling lucky.
```

becomes

```
The weather was <i>nice</i>**LF**

and Eve was feeling lucky.
```

Does anyone has any idea where it could come from?

The code :

```
case 'Texte':
$this->setData('body', $domElement);
```

Comment: post your code also to let us see?

Comment: It is not clear what `$this->setData()` does. Another point do you convert HTML to (X)HTML or one XML format into another XML format?

Comment: The program is to convert XML to another XML

The $this->setData() part is to explain the program which field the data is going to in the new XML.